# How to make 2 nodejs servers connect with SSL websocket?

Tags: node.js, https, socket.io

I am trying to make 2 servers communicate via `socket.io` library and SSL.

This used to work until an upgrade of `socket.io` package (can't tell you which).

I have managed to fix secure connection with a browser. I have also made it work between unsecure (http) servers. But the secure (https) servers refuse to connect between themselves. You may argue that `socket.io` is not made for server to server communications, but it would save me lots of work to fix it.

I am now running:

```
node: 7.5.0
express: 4.16.2
socket.io (and socket.io-client): 2.0.3
```

I cannot even make simple examples below work (removing all my middleware).

**node server**

```
// Use SSL certificate
const cert_path = "..";
const fs = require('fs');
const https_options = {
    key:  fs.readFileSync(cert_path+'/privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(cert_path+'/cert.pem')
};

const app = require('express')();

const https = require('https');
const server = https.createServer(https_options, app);

const io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(8000);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("connected");
});
```

**node client**

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');

const socket = io.connect(
    'https://localhost:8000',
    {secure: true}
);

socket.on("connect", function () {
    console.log("connected");
});
```

Nothing happens, none of them connect. Any idea why?

---

EDIT: I'm getting both `connect_error` and `reconnect_error` that pop every 5s on client side:

```
{ Error: xhr poll error
    at XHR.Transport.onError (../node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/transport.js:64:13)
    at Request.<anonymous> (../node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/transports/polling-xhr.js:128:10)
    at Request.Emitter.emit (../node_modules/component-emitter/index.js:133:20)
    at Request.onError (../node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/transports/polling-xhr.js:310:8)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (../node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/transports/polling-xhr.js:257:18)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5) type: 'TransportError', description: 503 }
```

Digging further in the errors, I see it may come from the certificate. But while I apply several workarounds of SO, I'm getting consecutively ECONNREFUSED, UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE, and finally DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT...

Comment: Have you verified your synchronous loading of credentials are not taking longer than it takes to load your server?  If it's an issue, then you may consider using `fs.readFile` (asynchronous version) or just use an environment variable using `dotenv` instead, and avoid sync or async operations entirely.

Comment: It's reading fine, that's not the problem. It works when serving `wss` to a web page.

Comment: have you tried adding a listener on error events in your client? I don't have experience with socket.io,  but a quick look at the API doc and I found: https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#event-connect_error.

Comment: Great idea: I'm getting a **reconnect_error**. I edit with this.

Comment: Do you have matching versions of `socket.io` and `socket.io-client`?  In the most recent major version release for socket.io, the client is no longer compatible with older servers and vice versa.

Comment: @jfriend00: yes they are both on same (and latest) version. The client pops an error even before I start the server. I think now it's caused by the certificate. But I'm stuck there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying hard:

- re-generate my **Let's Encrypt** certificate
- re-generate my **self-signed** certificates (openssl) and use them by server+client
- tinker with **socket.io** `connect` options (secure, rejectUnauthorized, ..)
- tinker with **nodejs** global setup even (`process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED']`)

I finally stumbled on [this page of github](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2419). It solved my issue and it's worth sharing it.

**node client**

```
const https = require('https');
https.globalAgent.options.rejectUnauthorized = false;

const io = require('socket.io-client');
const sockets = io.connect('https://localhost:8001', {agent: https.globalAgent});
```

Even if I would have preferred getting my connection authorized in the first place, this will work for me.